# Pandas: Create a column based on applying string conditions on other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
    KPI             Tata    JSW 
Gross Margin %      0.582   0.476   
EBITDA Margin %     0.191   0.23    
EBIT Margin %       0.145   0.183   
SG&A/Revenue        0.141   0.03    
COGS/Revenue        0.418   0.524   
CapE/Revenue        0.0577  0.1204      
ROA                 0.064   0.093   
ROE                 0.138   0.243       
Revenue/Employee $K 290.9   934.4   
Inventory Turnover  2.2     3.27    
AR Turnover         13.02   14.29   
Tot Asset Turnover  0.68    0.74    
Current Ratio       0.9     0.8 
Quick Ratio         0.3     0.4
```

I am trying to add a column, say, `scope` based on the following criterion:

```
if df[df['KPI'].str.contains('Margin|Revenue|ROE|ROA')].shape[0] > 0:
  z = 'Max'
elif df[df['KPI'].str.contains('Quick|Current|Turnover')].shape[0] > 0:
  z = 'Min'
```

In other words, If the field `KPI` contains any word like `Revenue` or `Margin` then the column `scope` should take `Max` else `Min`. Now there is an exception in `KPI == COGS/Revenue` or `KPI == CapEx/Revenue`. In this case the `scope` should take `Min` despite the string `Revenue` is present.

So the resultant `df` should look like below:

[image: Resultant Dataframe]

In order to achieve the same I am trying to `apply` a function on the field `KPI`.

```
def scope_superlative(col_name):
  df_test = df[df[col_name].str.contains('Margin| Revenue|ROA|ROE')]
  if df_test.shape[0] > 0:
    z = 'Max'
  else:
    df_test = df[df[col_name].str.contains('/Revenue|Current|Quick|Turnover')] ##<-- I want to check if string 'Revenue' is in denominator.##
    if df_test.shape[0] > 0:
      z='Min'
  return z
##Applying this function##
df['scope'] = df.KPI.apply(lambda x : scope_superlative(x))
```

The above code is generating an `Error` as  `KeyError: 'Gross Margin %`

If I use `df['scope']=df.apply(scope_superlative('KPI'), axis=1)` I get an Error as `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Max'`.

Can anybody please help on this? Is there anything wrong in function or applying technique?

Comment: Instead of posting photo of your data. Post it as text. So its easy to copy for others.

Comment: @Poojan: I have edited the input df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def fn(row):
    if re.search('/Revenue|Current|Quick|Turnover', row['KPI']):
        return 'Min'
    elif re.search('Margin|Revenue|ROA|ROE', row['KPI']):
        return 'Max'

df = pd.read_csv('so.csv')

df['scope'] = df.apply (lambda row: fn(row), axis=1)
print (df)
```

This simply uses `df.apply()` function which takes each row and applies the provided function on it.

This gives following result on given data:

```
0        Gross Margin %    0.5820    0.4760   Max
1       EBITDA Margin %    0.1910    0.2300   Max
2         EBIT Margin %    0.1450    0.1830   Max
3          SG&A/Revenue    0.1410    0.0300   Min
4          COGS/Revenue    0.4180    0.5240   Min
5          CapE/Revenue    0.0577    0.1204   Min
6                   ROA    0.0640    0.0930   Max
7                   ROE    0.1380    0.2430   Max
8   Revenue/Employee $K  290.9000  934.4000   Max
9    Inventory Turnover    2.2000    3.2700   Min
10          AR Turnover   13.0200   14.2900   Min
11   Tot Asset Turnover    0.6800    0.7400   Min
12        Current Ratio    0.9000    0.8000   Min
13          Quick Ratio    0.3000    0.4000   Min
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried this and it did not work. `AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'contains'", 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: The OP doesn't say everything other than `'Margin| Revenue|ROA|ROE'` has to be min. @Kaushal28 and your way is not efficient because when you do `df.apply` the entire row gets selected per iteration. But the operation is only needed in one column.

Comment: Updated the code @pythondumb. Just change the conditions in `fn` function based on your requirements

Comment: @Vishnudev Yes I know but condition is not that important in this case. I'm just suggesting a possible approach to OP.

Comment: @Kaushal28: I am getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @pythondumb there might be something wrong with input...Code is working in my environment with given data...Can you tell me the line number of error?

Comment: @Kaushal28: Yes I have rectified the code in my notebook. It is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @pythondumb After having some years of experience with using pandas, you'll realise that using apply was the worst mistake that you made. Keep in mind that not everything that gets work done is good.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for multiple conditions and values

```
conditions = [
    df['KPI'].str.contains('Margin| Revenue|Revenue/|ROE|ROA'),
    df['KPI'].str.contains('/Revenue|Current|Quick|Turnover')
]
values = ['Max', 'Min']
df['scope'] = pd.np.select(conditions, values, default='Min/Max')
```

Keep the `default` parameter to the value you desire when all conditions don't match.

OR

If you have only one condition, then,

```
condition = df['KPI'].str.contains('Margin| Revenue|ROE|ROA')
df['scope'] = pd.np.where(condition, 'Max', 'Min')
```

The first parameter to `np.where` is the condition, second is value to put when True and third is value to put when False

Comment: your code worked! I just edited a little and it worked. I wonder why can't we use simple `apply` method here?

Comment: @pythondumb Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code. The above code is vectorized.

Comment: @pythondumb check my answer it will work using apply method.

Comment: @Vishnudev +1 for the reference you provided for apply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- you can use `apply` function on column you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
d = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a b c','b c d','p q r','d e f','c b a'],'b':[1,2,3,4,5]})

d['scope'] = d['a'].apply(lambda x: 'MAX' if re.search('a|b|e', x) else 'MIN')

d
```

Output:

```
      a     b   scope
0   a b c   1   MAX
1   b c d   2   MAX
2   p q r   3   MIN
3   d e f   4   MAX
4   c b a   5   MAX
```

- for your data this should work.

```
df['Scope'] = df['KPI'].apply(lambda x: 'MAX' if re.search('Margin| Revenue|ROE|ROA', x) else 'MIN')
```

Comment: How to tackle the exception? I.e. `COGS/Revenue` as it should take 'Min'. As per your logic it would take 'Max'

Comment: @pythondumb Check now.